# Проблемы с кнопкой Backspace

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, json

Проблема с виртуальной кнопкой Backspace, так как она удаляет не только номер но и маску которая задает формат для номера. Кто с этим сталкивался подскажите как можно решить эту проблему ?

Вот скрипт кнопки :

```
 function del(){
    var str = document.getElementById('phone').value;
    parseInt(str)
    document.getElementById('phone').value = str.substring(0, str.length-1);
    console.log(str)
    }
```

вот разметка кнопки :

```
<input type="button" class="mybutton" onclick="del()" data-paste="→" value="→"/>
```

Вот полный код :https://jsfiddle.net/0xL0fctq/98/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда вы используете маску (кстати, вы не указали сам скрипт, поэтому я использую свои телепатические способности), то скрипт подменяет содержимое input в html-строку с заданными правилами форматирования маски.

Что можно сделать:

1) Посмотреть на скрипт маски, нет ли у него функций типа setValue, которая обходит разметку маски?

или

2) Перед нажатием этой кнопки вызывать у скрипта маски destroy() (или что у него там, тут телепатия не помогает) на этом input, изменять значение, а потом снова его "создавать".